# Another "which" question

Tags: grammar

In this sentence

> Green tea contains the vitamins and healthy properties of the green tea leaf, which makes green tea popular among health-conscious people.

what is the "which" referring to?? Is it referring to the green tea leaf or the vitamins and healthy properties?

Answer (score 2):

The way I read it, **which** refers to the whole phrase: not the leaf, nor the properties and vitamins, but to the assertion that green tea contains these things.
Admittedly, it's a little ambiguous.

I have seem examples where there would be a noun or noun-phrase after the **which** to clarify  the writer's meaning:

> Green tea contains the vitamins and healthy properties of the green tea leaf, **which fact**  makes green tea popular among health-conscious people.

Or that could be rewritten as

> ... green tea leaf, **a fact which** ...

Comment: The fact that the verb is *makes*, not *make*, shows that you are correct. It's not ambiguous, just a little unexpected.

Comment: Yes, the clue here is in the word **makes**, which must refer to a singular noun, and how, you might ask, could the *leaf* make the tea popular all by itself? But it's the sort of thing you have to read a couple of times to convince yourself that you've read it the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it refers to the entire clause, or you could think of it as an implied noun:

Green tea contains the vitamins and healthy properties of the green tea leaf, *(a fact)* which makes it popular.